# Encrypt a string in Delphi 7 using DCPCrypt (3DES)

Tags: delphi, encryption, delphi-7, 3des

I need to encrypt a string in Delphi 7. The only encryption library I managed to get running is DCPCrypt.

I studied an example that encrypted files, and tried to adapt it for strings, but I'm afraid I failed miserably...

This is my function:

```
function Encrypt3DES(psString, psKey: string): string;
var
    lCipher:TDCP_3des;
    CipherIV: array of byte;     // the initialisation vector (for chaining modes)
    lHash:TDCP_sha256;
    lHashDigest: array of byte;   // the result of hashing the passphrase with the salt
    Salt: array[0..7] of byte;   // a random salt to help prevent precomputated attacks
    i:integer;
begin
    lHash:=TDCP_sha256.Create(nil);
    SetLength(lHashDigest,lHash.HashSize div 8);
    for i := 0 to 7 do
      Salt[i] := Random(256);  // just fill the salt with random values (crypto secure PRNG would be better but not _really_ necessary)

    //strmOutput.WriteBuffer(Salt,Sizeof(Salt));  // write out the salt so we can decrypt! ***I don't know what to do with this***

    lHash.Init;
    lHash.Update(Salt[0],Sizeof(Salt));   // hash the salt
    lHash.UpdateStr(psKey);  // and the passphrase
    lHash.Final(lHashDigest[0]);           // store the output in HashDigest

    lCipher:=TDCP_3des.Create(nil);
    //3DES is a block cipher, we need an initialisation vector

    SetLength(CipherIV,TDCP_blockcipher(lCipher).BlockSize div 8);
    for i := 0 to (Length(CipherIV) - 1) do
      CipherIV[i] := Random(256);           // again just random values for the IV

    //strmOutput.WriteBuffer(CipherIV[0],Length(CipherIV));  // write out the IV so we can decrypt! ***I don't know what to do with this***

    lCipher.Init(lHashDigest[0],TNeo.Min(lCipher.MaxKeySize,lHash.HashSize),CipherIV);  // initialise the cipher with the hash as key
    TDCP_blockcipher(lCipher).CipherMode := cmCBC;   // use CBC chaining when encrypting

    //lCipher.EncryptStream(strmInput,strmOutput,strmInput.Size); // encrypt the entire file
    result:=lCipher.EncryptString(psString);
    lCipher.Burn;   // important! get rid of keying information
    //strmInput.Free;
    //strmOutput.Free;
end;
```

Please, bear in mind that I am completely ignorant on how encryption works. I know you don't encrypt string, but binaries, but I don't know how to translate that to code.
Every time I run it, I get a different result (I guess it's normal if you use random values), but I don't know if it should be like that, since I have to send this to another server so they can check the integrity there.

Thay gave me a Java function in the API, but obviously I can't use it:

```
public byte [] encrypt_3DES(final String claveHex, final String datos) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, UnsupportedEncodingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    byte [] ciphertext = null;
    // Crea la clave
    DESedeKeySpec desKeySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(toByteArray(claveHex));
    SecretKey desKey = new SecretKeySpec(desKeySpec.getKey(), "DESede");
    // Crea un cifrador
    Cipher desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/NoPadding");

    // Inicializa el cifrador para encriptar
    desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, desKey, new IvParameterSpec(IV));

    // Se añaden los 0 en bytes necesarios para que sea un múltiplo de 8
    int numeroCerosNecesarios = 8 - (datos.length() % 8);
    if (numeroCerosNecesarios == 8) {
        numeroCerosNecesarios = 0;
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream array = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    array.write(datos.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, datos.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < numeroCerosNecesarios; i++) {
        array.write(0);
    }
    byte [] cleartext = array.toByteArray();
    // Encripta el texto
    ciphertext = desCipher.doFinal(cleartext);
    return ciphertext;
}
```

I any kind soul could give me a hand with this, I'd be really grateful. I've been banging my head against this for several days.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMHO AES should be preferred to 3DES... And our [SynCrypto.pas](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/blob/master/SynCrypto.pas) Open Source unit works perfectly with Delphi 7. From C#, with PKCS7 padding, see http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=3395

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez+. Exactly. 3DES is not safe already for a 20 years..

Comment: That's great, but it's not really my call (I have to adapt our system for an online payment system). I have to send a form using HMAC with SHA256. They ask you to prepare a form in JSON, Base64 encode it, prepare a trasansaction-unique key, and add a SHA256 signature based on the encoded form and the transaction-unique key. That key is calculated encrypting with 3DES our secret password and the transaction ID. This is where I'm stuck.

Comment: For D7, I used to use Lockbox which is open source https://sourceforge.net/p/tplockbox/wiki/Home/  If you're interested in trying that, I can post code to encrypt a string, which with Lockbox is very easy..

Comment: @JohnEasley Thanks John. Please do. I'll install Lockbox right away to try it out. Thanks you very much!

Comment: Rev 12 has this /DCPcrypt/Docs/Ciphers.html#Example1 which shows how to encrypt a string and also includes a TestCipher function.

Comment: @Tarrakis It is you call if you are willing to make it,you can always say "No." Otherwise you are contributing to the security fail we are currently seeing and given that your code may well continue in use for years you are helping create an on-going security failure. It is such a shame to see new code that is not secure.

Comment: @zaph, I really can't. It's either that, or my company has to stop accepting credit card payments. In Spain there is only one main credit card processing center (all banks use it). Foreign solutions usually don't implement 3D Secure. Anyway, I think that using 3DES to create a key that adds security to HMAC256 is quite secure, as long as HMAC256 is secure.

Comment: Ah yes, the payments industry is still in the process of migrating to AES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example uses the Open Source TLockBox library to encrypt/decrypt a string using 3DES https://sourceforge.net/p/tplockbox/wiki/Home/

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls,
  //lockbox units 
  LbCipher, LbClass, LbAsym, LbRSA, LbString;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    edPlainText: TEdit;
    edCipherText: TEdit;
    btnEncryptString: TButton;
    btnDescryptString: TButton;
    procedure btnEncryptStringClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnDescryptStringClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

Function TripleDesEncrypt(const APlaintext, APassphrase: String): String;
Var
  Key128: TKey128;
begin
  GenerateLMDKey(Key128, SizeOf(Key128), APassphrase);
  result  := TripleDESEncryptStringEx(APlainText, Key128, True);
End;

Function TripleDesDecrypt(const ACipherText, APassphrase: String): String;
Var
  Key128: TKey128;
begin
  GenerateLMDKey(Key128, SizeOf(Key128), APassphrase);
  Try
    result := TripleDESEncryptStringEx(ACipherText, Key128, False);
  Except
    Result := '';
  End;
End;

procedure TForm1.btnEncryptStringClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  edCipherText.text := TripleDesEncrypt(edPlainText.Text, 'SecretPassphrase');
end;

procedure TForm1.btnDescryptStringClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  edPlainText.text := TripleDesDecrypt(edCipherText.text, 'SecretPassphrase');
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thank you so much, John. I'll try it on monday and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I found out later that I was using the wrong DCPCrypt function as a guide.
I'll post the other one I found, in case someone needs to use DCPCrypt:

```
function Encrypt3DES(psData, psKey: string): string;
var
    Cipher: TDCP_3des;
begin
    Cipher:= TDCP_3des.Create(nil);
    Cipher.InitStr(psKey,TDCP_sha256);         // initialize the cipher with a hash of the passphrase
    result:=Cipher.EncryptString(psData);
    Cipher.Burn;
    Cipher.Free;
end;
```